# Show images in recylerView of a chat application in android using Retrofit

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, chat, retrofit, android-image

I'm working on a chat application using **Rrtrofit**. By following [Sendbird](https://blog.sendbird.com/android-chat-tutorial-building-a-messaging-ui/) I'm creating the chat conversation activity.The problem is I don't understand how to show the images that conversation. Specially when it a chat application images can comes randomly. As showing on blog If I'm trying to set an imageView for both sender and reciver view but don't understand how to handle it.

Here is my RecyclerView.ViewHolder :

```
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(final ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view;
    if (viewType == VIEW_TYPE_MESSAGE_SENT) {
        view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.item_message_sent, parent, false);
        return new SentMessageHolder(view);

    } else if (viewType == VIEW_TYPE_MESSAGE_RECEIVED){
        view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.item_message_received, parent, false);
        return new ReceivedMessageHolder(view);
    }
    return null;
}



// Passes the message object to a ViewHolder so that the contents can be bound to UI.
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Datum2 message = (Datum2) data.get(position);

    switch (holder.getItemViewType()) {
        case VIEW_TYPE_MESSAGE_SENT:
            ((SentMessageHolder) holder).bind(message);

            break;
        case VIEW_TYPE_MESSAGE_RECEIVED:
            ((ReceivedMessageHolder) holder).bind(message);
    }

}
```

As I've to view I worked for Sender and Receiver separately so following code is my **SentMessageHolder**

```
    private class SentMessageHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView messageText, timeText;
    String rec_id;
    String content_id;
    int[] ids = new int[100];

    SentMessageHolder(final View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        messageText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_message_body);
        timeText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_message_time);
    }
    void bind(Datum2 message) {
        messageText.setText(message.getMsg());

        // Format the stored timestamp into a readable String using method.
        timeText.setText(message.getCreatedAt().getFormatTime());
        content_id = message.getContentId().toString();
        if (! message.getOriginatorId().equals(userID)){
            rec_id.valueOf(message.getOriginatorId());
        }
        else {
            rec_id = null;
        }
    }
}
```

and as well as my **ReceivedMessageHolder** is :

```
    private class ReceivedMessageHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView messageText, timeText, nameText;

    ImageView profileImage;
    ReceivedMessageHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        messageText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_message_body);
        timeText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_message_time);
        nameText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_message_name);
        profileImage =  itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_message_profile);
    }
    void bind(Datum2 message) {
        messageText.setText(message.getMsg());

        // Format the stored timestamp into a readable String using method.
        timeText.setText(message.getCreatedAt().getFormatTime());
        nameText.setText(message.getOriginator().getFullName());

        // Insert the profile image from the URL into the ImageView.
        Glide.with(mContext).load("my website url" + data.get(getLayoutPosition())
                .getOriginator().getAvatar()).apply(RequestOptions.circleCropTransform())
                .into(profileImage);
    }
}
```

This is my modal class for images:

```
public class Attributes {
@SerializedName("sticker")
@Expose
private String sticker;

@SerializedName("images")
@Expose
private List<String> images;

public String getSticker() {
    return sticker;
}

public void setSticker(String sticker) {
    this.sticker = sticker;
}

public List<String> getImages() {
    return images;
}

public void setImages(List<String> images) {
    this.images = images;
}
}
```

My json is like this :

```
"msg": "hi",
"attributes": {
"sticker": "",
"images": [
"94507a424a69870f090855274902bb7c.jpeg"
]
```

So what to do for retrieve my images in my conversation? Need Help.

Comment: Repalce "URL" with your base url  like 
" "https://www.basesite.com/images/"".

Comment: I got you're point. I used there my own web url for showing the profile picture of the user there. But I need something else. Showing images sent by anone

Comment: Where are you storing images?

Comment: I've another url for storing image like"https://example.com/uploads/images/" but here I'm doing nothing till now as I dont understand the issue...that url stores my all kind of images including chat image and other featured image.

Comment: @RonakJoshi you get my pont?

Comment: Are your images values stored in a variable of type "Attributes" of "Datum2" class ?

Comment: Uploading image is not done yet.But I'll get it from "Attribute" class as chatting on my web is done already.I need to show the images chatted from web. @smora

Comment: How you will retrieve your images is decisive in how you will add them in the chat. I see two ways, add a third and fourth types of items/messages, "images_sent" and "images_received" and their corresponding item views. Or add images in actual models of "message_send" and "message_received". Then in both case you should add an empty viewGroup in item_view layout to be able to add in it programatically the appropriate number of ImageViews.

Comment: Can you please refer my any tutorial or any sample for doing this? I'm stuck still

Comment: It seems that you're having a problem loading images with Glide? Is  `Glide.with(mContext).load(url)` not working? Here `url` should be the full path to your image, i.e.) `com.example.com/uploads/images/94507a424a69870f090855274902bb7c.jpeg`.